Flutter get_cli package installation failure
I'm using get_cli to manage my flutter app file stacture, but when i'm installing the package i'm getting an error, i have clean the pub cache but i can't solve it need help.
I'm using flutter version "Flutter 3.22.0" and I'm using pop os
the error is
Failed to build get_cli:get:
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dcli-2.3.0/lib/src/util/wait_for_ex.dart:38:17: Error: Method not found: 'waitFor'.
        value = cli.waitFor<T>(wrapped);
            ^^^^^^^


I tried the solution here and it worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78287733/15446019

It didn't work for me, i have also tried that

Try this  flutter pub global activate --source=git "https://github.com/inyong1/get_cli.git"
